# Multiple Inheritance and AppDelegate in iOS (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, multiple-inheritance, appdelegate

I'm trying to implement delegates in my iOS app (swift 2) but am getting the error "Multiple inheritance from classes 'UIViewController' and 'AppDelegate'."  I created a new MyAppDelegate from a blank swift file and got the same error (but with 'MyAppDelegate').  The code for MyAppDelegate.swift is below:

```
import Foundation
import MediaPlayer

class InstatunesAppDelegate {    
}
```

I'm implementing it here and getting the error:

```
class myViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, InstatunesAppDelegate {
```

I'm still trying to wrap my head around delegates...  How is MyAppDelegate a superclass?  If I define protocols and delegates in AppDelegate, how do I call them in other classes?  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks in advance...

Comment: Please explain how you're trying to use delegates. What wants to use a delegate and what functions will it call on the delegate? You use protocols to define what the delegate needs to do, then a class conforms to that protocol. Note that you shouldn't be giving the app delegate extra responsibility, it should just be the app delegate and nothing else...

Comment: There is no multiple inheritance in swift. `InstatunesAppDelegate` must be a protocol.

Comment: The _first_ item after the colon can be a class. The rest must be protocols. InstatunesAppDelegate is a class, not a protocol.

Comment: Wain - It's really a pretty simple app.  All I need to do is pass a couple properties (even just a string of text in some cases) amongst a few classes...I don't even require methods be passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out what I was really after was more of a global delegate, established in AppDelegate.swift and available in any class where I call:

```
let delegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
```

Thanks to those who responded...

Answer (score 0):

Swift does not support multiple class inherence. You inherit one class and other protocols.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple inheritance at a time is not allowed. If you carefully checkout you ViewController class then you can see that actually it is inherited from UIViewController class and others(UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource) are actually protocol. That means ViewController class confirm these protocol not inherited. If you want to do so then just change "class" before the InstatunesAppDelegate and named it as "protocol" as like bellow:

```
protocol InstatunesAppDelegate{

}
```

For better understanding checkout this link [protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html)